# Datatable partial sorting efficient

Tags: c#

Need to order a `datatable` by partial condition. Have a `datatable` in this way:

```
[0]: P01,10,01; 
[1]: P01,10,02;
     ... 
[n]: P03,10,01;
     ... 
[m]: P03,10,02;
```

What I need to do is ordering the `datatable` by a partial portion of data; Example: When first row is odd it must be in descending order, while a pair must by in ascending.
The value returned must look like:

```
[0]: P02,10,01; 
[1]: P02,10,02;
     ... 
[n]: P03,10,03;
     ... 
[m]: P03,10,02;
```

I know that a sort in `datatable` and default dataview can do that.
How can I sort this data in a `datatable`?

Comment: Your sorting criteria make no sense. What does "When first row is odd" mean? Can you give a more complete example, with an explanation?

Comment: Means: when Pxx where xx is odd the order must be descending. So: P02  must be ascending; P03 must be descending

Comment: As far as I know, you can't sort a `DataTable` directly. You can create a `DataView`, sort it, and create a new `DataTable`, as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108171/56778. But it doesn't look like you can specify sorting criteria that will do what you want.

Comment: Yes, by this way you can sort a datatable: dt.Select("ROW TO FILTER= 'VALUE TO FILTER'", "COLUMN DESC"). The value dt is passing by as a datatable parameter, and the COLUMN is the order by

Comment: So you're not wanting to sort the table in-place, but rather to sort the results returned from a `Select`. Nevertheless, I don't think the expression syntax is sufficiently expressive for your needs.

Comment: I could do in-place or even in a returned value, but i want to know the more eficient way to do it