# How to show merge tables(number of tables) data in descending order according to date/time column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

How to show merge tables(number of tables) data in descending order according to date/time column?

According to this code I have a table named 'Friend'.

```
SqlDataAdapter getnewsfeeds;
SqlDataAdapter friendadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + Session["username"].ToString() + "_friends ", friendsconnection);
friendadapter.Fill(friendsdataset);
int friendrowcount = friendsdataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
if (friendrowcount > 0)
{
      getnewsfeeds = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + Session["username"].ToString() + "_newsfeeds ", con);
      getnewsfeeds.Fill(ds2);
      for (int i = 0; i < friendrowcount; i++)
      {
          friendstringtable = " " + friendsdataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["friendsusername"].ToString() + "_newsfeeds ";
          getnewsfeeds = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + friendstringtable + "", con);
          getnewsfeeds.Fill(ds2);
      }

}
ds2.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "time_date desc";
```

Data of merge tables are showing but it is not showing according to date/time in descending order. (For eg Facebook Homepage).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it in-place, you're going to need to create a new `DataTable`:

```
DataView dv = ds2.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "time_date desc";
DataTable sorted = dv.ToTable();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108171/940072) is a good reference.

Having said that, wouldn't it be better/easier/faster to do it in your sql query ?

```
getnewsfeeds = new SqlDataAdapter(
   "select * from " + friendstringtable + " order by time_date desc", con);
```

And while this is not your question, my advice is NOT to have a table for each user. I know most people don't come here for "advice", but rather for direct answer, however in this case I'm afraid I have to say something.