# DataTable Sorting Then Assign Sorted Table Back To Original Table

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a dataset that has a table called detail I want to sort. I know using a dataview I can sort the table with the following code..

```
Dim dvParsedDataset As New DataView(parsedDataset.Tables("Detail"))
            dvParsedDataset.Sort = AuthorizatonConstants.Auth_ID
```

I want to not only sort the table but assign it back to the original table in this case `parsedDataset.Tables("Detail")` but when assigning the sorted view back I get a read only error

```
parsedDataset.Tables("Detail") = dvParsedDataset.ToTable 'READ ONLY ERROR
```

How do I sort the table and also override the original table with the sorted table?

Comment: are you using this with a datagridview? There's a datagridview sorting that you could use.

Comment: no there is no GUI, I am using just the dataset

Comment: Ah, in that case you may want to look at this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the previous DataTable from the DataSet and the add the new table

```
DataTable detailCopy = dvParsedDataset.ToTable("Detail")
parsedDataset.Tables.Remove("Detail") 
parsedDataset.Tables.Add(detailCopy)
```