# Dynamic Button c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have some problems with dynamic button in c#. I have developed an application for Pos and I need to create group of product but when I click on group button I have to show product sorting by name of product group.

This is my code:

```
private void Pos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=programmj;allowuservariables=True");
    conn.Open();

    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM priduct_group");

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    int top = 0;
    int left = 4;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
             Button button = new Button();
             button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
             button.BackColor = Color.Gold;
             button.Text = dr[1].ToString();
             button.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
             button.Size = new Size(170, 85);
             button.Left = left;
             button.Top = top;
             panel8.Controls.Add(button); // here
             top += button.Height + 2;
             button.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);
    }
}
```

And this is my another code for displaying product

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=programmj;allowuservariables=True");
    conn.Open();

    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblartikujt ");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    int top = 0;
    int left = 4;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
            panel5.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Padding = new Padding(20, 3, 20, 3);
            button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            button.ForeColor = Color.White;
            button.BackColor = Color.Green;
            button.Text = dr[3].ToString();
            button.Text = dr[10].ToString();
            button.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
            button.Size = new Size(200, 85);
            button.Left = left;
            button.Top = top;
            panel5.Controls.Add(button); // here
            top += button.Height + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you have a problem but you didn't explain what problem that is....

Comment: My problem is that cant display product sort by product name ?
i have on table product , and on table product type i need to show product by product type ? do you understand me ?

Comment: OK...and what part of your code is trying to do that because I see no sort code anywhere, only adding buttons to, I have to assume, different panels....

Comment: panel 8 is for displaying the product type and the panel 5 is for product the problem is in panel 5 ? can display product on panel 5 sorting by product type in panel 8 ?

Comment: It would be easier I guess if your datatable was bound to a [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) because the events are then fired in the context of the grid. By the look of it you try to do the heavy lifting yourself. That is not easy...

Comment: Can we talk with e-mail ?

Comment: No, we can't. You can provide all info  here if you [edit] your question. This scales better as more people will read your question.

Comment: Can you update your question with more detail about the problem you are dealing with? I'm not sure if you have difficulty writing a correct SQL query or C# code on Winform.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems quite vague, but let me try.

Are you asking how to allocate the `button` in the method `Pos_Load` in a sorted way?
 
(By doing so, the `panel8` will contain buttons in the way you have sorted.)

If that's what you're asking, you can simply write your SQL query using `order by` as follows:

```
SELECT
        *
FROM
        product_group
ORDER BY
        product_name
DESC
```

With a query like that above, you can control your `DataRow` to be **selected in order**, which will cause your `button` to have  the sorted `DataRow's` information.

Comment: If, for some strange reason, you can't alter the query, you can use [Sorting rows in a data table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108171/3191303) to help you sort the results that you've already received, but YayCplusplus's answer should meet what sounds like your needs are.