# Dynamically choosing what row data is added to a table

Tags: c#, tablerow

Adding a table dynamically in code behind I can do something like...

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
cell1.Text = "blah blah blah";
row.Cells.Add(cell1);
myTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

but what if the order of the table rows depends on the user input....so for each iteration it is either going to be A or B. If it is A, extend row a...If it is B, extend row b

```
after 1st iteration
A: 123

after 2nd iteration
A: 123
B: abc

after 3rd iteration
A: 123456
B abc

after 4th iteration
A: 123456789
B: abc
```

Ive tried rows.addAt(index, row);  but its not working says index is out of range. is this even the correct way to do this? thanks for any replies

```
    //forloop
   {
    if(A)
    {
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Text = "blah blah blah";
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    myTable.Rows.AddAt(0, row);
    }

    if(B)
    {
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Text = "blah blah blah";
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    myTable.Rows.Add(1, row);
    }
```

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want to change the value of row A or row B, or you add rows and the most recent have to be at indeces 0 and 1?

Comment: How about using sorting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table

Comment: @Gnqz after each iteration I want to extend the data in either row A or row B...adding the new value to end of the row...maybe I should have done it at the cell level and added the cell to the row?

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is that each time you are creating a new row/cell instead of getting the reference to an existing row/cell.  If I understand correctly, your table has 2 rows, each with 1 cell, and you're trying to grow the contents?

You need to do something more like this.  Note that I have not tested this:

```
TableCell existingCell = myTable.Rows[0].Cells[0];
existingCell.Text += "NewData";
```

Or if you wanted to add new cells to the existing rows it would be similar:

```
TableRow existingRow = myTable.Rows[0];
TableCell newCell = new TableCell();
newCell.Text = "NewData";
existingRow.add(newCell);
```

Comment: this does not work .rows() cant be used like a method in this situation. thanks though

Comment: Sorry, I've been doing a lot of VBA recently and that was very similar.  .Rows() will return a TableRowCollection.  You can use [0] to get an element from that collection.  I've updated  the example code.