# Why does CopyToDataTable unsort the DataRow Array

Tags: c#, datatable, sorting

I've got a datatable that I need to sort and place back into another datatable. On the face of this its easy as below:

```
 DataTable sortme = getdata();
 sortme.Select("col1 = 'something'", "sortbyme ASC").CopytoDataTable();
```

However, I've found as soon as I pass the DataRow array created by select() to CopytoDataTable(), the new datatable is no longer sorted by `sortbyme`.

How do I fix this without creating a loop to push each DataRow into a datatable? And what is causing the sorting to be lost?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a question asked and solved about how to sort DataTables by row, please look at it here, it might help you:

[Sorting rows in a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table)

Comment: This does not answer my question. I want to know why CopytoDataTable is not working as expected, because I need to do more than sort.

Comment: Could you give me a little bit more insight? What is the current outcome of it?