# How to sort a data table items base on ID in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to C# and SQL and I am using windows forms.

[image: screenshot]

As shown in the screenshot I am saving items to `SQL` `table` and then I read them to create `buttons` in `flowLayoutPanel`. The following code works fine but the problem is : when I read the items and add them to the `flowLayoutPanel`, they are added as they are in `DataTable` (unsorted).

Anyone knows how to add the `buttons` (Items) to `flowLayoutPanel` and re-order them based on their `ID` ? I mean I want to add them to `flowLayoutPanel` as : Item1 ,Item2, Item3, Item4 .

Thank you.

```
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Sql_Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();



                DataTable.Rows.Clear();
                DataTable.Columns.Clear();
                MyConnection.Open();
                MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_Items";
                MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
                Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);

                MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                Sql_Data_Adapter.Dispose();
                MyConnection.Close();


                int RowIndex = DataTable.Rows.Count - 1;


                for (int i = 0; i <= RowIndex; i++)
                {

                    // create buttons

                    Button btn = new Button();                       

                    btn.Text = DataTable.Rows[i]"Item_Name"].ToString();
                    btn.Name = DataTable.Rows[i]["Item_Name"].ToString();              

                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);

                }
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably: `SELECT * FROM Table_Items ORDER BY ID;`

Comment: Change query to `SELECT * FROM Table_Items ORDER BY Item_Name`

Comment: Yeah or as @Crowcoder said, sort in the DB query.

Comment: @ Crowcoder. worked like magic :) . thank you

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya . thank you too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting rows in a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your SQL Query to -

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Items ORDER BY Id
```