# Sorting DataTable by data in List

Tags: c#, datatables

I have DataTable filled with data from my database. What I need is sort:

Here is example dataTable:

```
ID_Column
1
2
3
4
5
```

And here is my List<>:

```
2
3
5
```

I need to sort DataTable by data that occur in my List. After sorting DataTable should be like this:

```
ID_Column
2
3
5
1
4
```

Is this possible to achieve this type of sorting in DataTable?
I don't need to have same order like items in my List. Just need to have all items from list on top of DataTable.

Last time someone marked this as duplicate and I received answer "how to sort List", but I asked to sort **DataTable**. DataTable is not List. I'm not able to use OrderBy() method on DataTable.

Comment: [Is this related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table)

Comment: Your solution doesn't include data in List, it's just sorts descending or ascending. I need to place all data with the same ID as in list on top of dataTable