# c# lambda linq order by multiple column's index

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a query just want to order by if ticketStatus = Attended first then Issue, then Unpaid, then Cancelled. Thanks

```
var duplicate = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy((x,index) => index(ticketStatusOrder.IndexOf(x["TicketStatus"].ToString())))
            //.OrderBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Attended")
            //.ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Issued")
            //.ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Unpaid")
            //.ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Cancelled")
            .GroupBy(x => new {EventID = x["EventID"].ToString(), ContactID = x["ContactID"].ToString()})
            .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Use a single `OrderBy`. Inside it, convert the string to an `TicketStatusOrdered` `enum` which is in the order you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-should-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out i can use with condition

```
       .OrderBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString())
        .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Attended")
        .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Issued")
        .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Unpaid")
        .ThenBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Cancelled")
```

Comment: You can reduce a `ThenBy` iteration by moving "Attended" to "OrderBy" like `.OrderBy(x => x["TicketStatus"].ToString() == "Attended")`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @mjwills answer, create an enum. But!

> You can't do an in-place sorting of a datatable, [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108171/1545359).

So, follow below two steps to sort your datatable.

1. Create an enum

   > enum TicketStatuses
   >       {
   >       Attended = 1,
   >       Issued = 2,
   >       Unpaid = 3,
   >       Cancelled = 4
   >   }
2. I tried below code in VS2017 and .Net Core 2 and is sorting properly as per your requirements.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id", typeof(String));
           dt.Columns.Add(dc);

           dc = new DataColumn("TicketStatus", typeof(TicketStatuses));
           dt.Columns.Add(dc);

           DataRow dr;
           //Adding test data of 6 rows
           for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
           {
               dr = dt.NewRow();

               dr[0] = i + 2; //Just a random column value - Could be anything here.
               dt.Rows.Add(dr);
           }
           // Setting column values for Column "TicketStatus" of our choice.
           dt.Rows[0][1] = TicketStatuses.Unpaid;
           dt.Rows[1][1] = TicketStatuses.Cancelled;
           dt.Rows[2][1] = TicketStatuses.Cancelled;
           dt.Rows[3][1] = TicketStatuses.Issued;
           dt.Rows[4][1] = TicketStatuses.Attended;
           dt.Rows[5][1] = TicketStatuses.Attended;
           dt.Rows[6][1] = TicketStatuses.Issued;

           //sorting datarows
           DataRow[] dataRows = dt.Select().OrderBy(u => u["TicketStatus"]).ToArray();

           DataTable sortedDatatable = dataRows.CopyToDataTable();
       }
   }
   ```

Cheers!

Comment: Those are for adding test data. Edited and added code comments. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: the ticketstatues are storing in the database cannot create one just like that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom comparer (but i guess that using enum is way better).
Also you can't use this comparer if your `OrderBy` should be translated to SQL query.

**Sample:**

```
public class TicketStatusComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private int GetIntValue( string value )
    {
        switch ( value )
        {
            case "Attended":
                return 1;
            case "Issue":
                return 2;
            case "Unpaid":
                return 3;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public int Compare( string x, string y )
    {
        return GetIntValue( x ) - GetIntValue( y );
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
var list = new[]
{
    new { A = 1, TicketStatus = "Issue" },
    new { A = 2, TicketStatus = "Attended" },
    new { A = 3, TicketStatus = "Unpaid" },
    new { A = 4, TicketStatus = "Attended" },
    new { A = 5, TicketStatus = "Unpaid" },
};

var xxx = list.OrderBy( x => x.TicketStatus, new TicketStatusComparer() ).ToList();
```